# Regex mask for MudTextField for minutes and seconds validation

Tags: c#, regex, validation, blazor, mudblazor

I have a text field for the user to pick a minutes+seconds time duration. I am trying to use a IMask object for restricting the input using a regex.

The problem is that this completely blocks the input, and I can not even begin to type a single digit, which I don't understand because as you can see on those links the two regex that I use work properly :

^[0-5]?\d:[0-5]\d$ https://regex101.com/r/ZKO3oE/1

^([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$ https://regex101.com/r/aM7NHi/1

My code looks like this and you can try it on the link below:

```
<MudTextField Mask="@mask1" Label="Duration"  HelperText="@mask1.Mask"
                  @bind-Value="minutesAndSec"  Variant="@Variant.Text" Clearable />

IMask mask1 = new RegexMask(@"^[0-5]?\d:[0-5]\d$");
```

You can try my code here:

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOQnbvPhASvzgOyF

I must be missing something? Any input is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot

Comment: As usual, you need to make sure your input (even incomplete) fully matches the pattern. In light of that, both your patterns must look like `@"^[0-5]?(?:\d(?::(?:[0-5]?\d)?)?)?$"` (use the same for both time and duration)

Comment: Try, `[1-9]\d*:(?:\d[1-9]|[1-5]\d)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your input (even incomplete) fully matches the pattern.

That means that both your patterns must look like

```cs
@"^[0-5]?(?:\d(?::(?:[0-5]?\d)?)?)?$"
```

Use the same pattern for both time and duration.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-5]?` - an optional digit from `0` to `5`
- `(?:\d(?::(?:[0-5]?\d)?)?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\d(?::(?:[0-5]?\d)?)?` - a digit and then an optional sequence of

    - `:(?:[0-5]?\d)?` - a `:` char and then an optional sequence of

      - `[0-5]?\d` - an optional `0` to `5` digit and then any single digit
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, customizing a control can be complex and may lead to various issues. Instead, you can use a time input type as follows:

```
<MudTextField T="string" Label="Duration" InputType="InputType.Time"/>
```

Comment: InputType.Time does not quite match was kind of value I need to represent though. I need to represent a time duration, expressed with a minutes and seconds component, separated by ':' and in the range from 0 to 59 minutes and 59 seconds. From what I have seen this type of input is not supported with MudBlazor.